# Supplying power to PCB with USB voltage (2.5V) regulator

Tags: power-supply, pcb, voltage-regulator

I am designing a normal PCB board. I want to put a USB voltage regulator to supply my PCB. I don't need to design the voltage regulator. I just want to add it to supply voltage in my PCB circuit. The output will always be 2.5V (not more than that). Which USB voltage regulator do you think will be good to add and is there any CAD model of that module so that I can add in my PCB design?

Comment: What do you mean with USB voltage regulator? USB voltage is 5V. Do you mean you want to boost from 2.5V to 5V? It is much easier if you edit the question and tell us your supply voltage, what voltage you require it to be regulated to, your current draw and any other constraints you may have, such as space/cost etc. Although think about how you word it because if you are just straight up asking what part to use, then product recommendation questions are *off topic* here

Comment: I meant the input to the voltage regulator will be USB type and the output will be 2.5V whatever the input is. The output will be connected to the circuit of my PCB. I want to know any good type of voltage regulator (means reliable) which I can solder on my PCB board.

Comment: People might be getting confused by the "input will always be 2.5V" language.  You should really edit your question to make what you're asking much clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clarification from OP I understand that the supply voltage is from a USB, and it needs to be regulated down to 2.5V.

If this is the case, then it is easy enough. You can simply go to an online retailer such as Digikey, Farnell, Mouser or any of the others and look through their voltage regulator section.

They have parameter searches, so if you want a particular package due to space constraints, then you can select that. You can then view results based on lowest price first if cost is an issue.

If you know the current your load will be drawing and you know any other specifications that may be important, then put those in as well. The search results will show you all the available ICs that fit your specs.

If you don't have any constraints, and it is a simple enough project, then any old 2.5V regulator that accepts a 5V input will do. If you do have a pretty heavy load, then be sure to check the thing won't heat up too much!

Comment: remember to look at the datasheet and check the recommended application circuit (usually there is one even if it's a diagram in some corner of a page).  Some regulators get finicky with their input and output capacitor values if you have long input power cables, etc.

Comment: DigiKey has a number of suitable DC-DC converter modules that are billed as linear voltage regulator replacements, if the OP doesn't want to burn up power in a linear regulator, or roll his own high-current switching supply.